# using user defined variable in model class variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to use a form variable inside a cakephp model class variable $actsAs.Below is an example code.

```
public $actsAs = array('MeioUpload' => array('doc' => array('allowedMime' => array('application/x-compressed','application/x-zip-compressed','application/zip','multipart/x-zip'),'dir'=>'uploads'.DS.$this->data['User']['foldername'])));
```

In the above code i have used a form variable (`$this->data['User']['foldername']`) in the `$actsAs` array for passing directory name to meioupload behaviour.

What can be the write process to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definition is wrong.

You can set that data from the constructor though.

```
public function __construct($data) {
    $this->actsAs = array('MeioUpload' => array('doc' => array('allowedMime' => array('application/x-compressed', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/zip', 'multipart/x-zip'), 'dir' => 'uploads' . DS . $data['User']['foldername'])));
}
```

Something like that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I added `parent::__construct();`  And `$this->Behaviors->init($this->alias,$this->actsAs);` and it works good.

Below is the modified code:

```
public function  __construct() {        
    parent::__construct();

    $this->actsAs = array('MeioUpload' => array('doc' => array('allowedMime' => array('application/x-compressed', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/zip', 'multipart/x-zip'), 'allowedExt' => array('.zip'),'dir' => 'uploads' . DS . $_REQUEST['data']['User']['foldername'])));

    $this->Behaviors->init($this->alias,$this->actsAs);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I’m changing path dynamically from controller.

CODE :

In Controller ( Where you specifying data to change value of $actsAs variable ) :

```
$custom_path=’/img/cakephp’;
Configure::write(‘path_var’,$custom_path);
```

In Model where you’ll change value in constructor :

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{
  $path = Configure::read(‘path_var’);
  // change actsAs’s different value according to your need
  $this->actsAs['Upload.Upload']['photo']['path'] = $path;
  parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

Please write statement Configure::write before model created.